# What is the symplectic structure of phase space?

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, topology, phase-space

What is called the symplectic structure of the phase space? How is Liuville theorem connected with smoothness of symplectic structure?

Comment: I am sure you have read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_vector_space  but I wonder, rather than a math treatment, are you looking (as am I), for an intuitive picture, if one exists. I think you should clarify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Here we will for simplicity only consider [manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold) within the category of [$C^{\infty}$-smooth manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold).
2. Assuming that the phase space is a [symplectic manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold) $(M,\omega)$, the symplectic structure is provided by a closed non-degenerate 2-form $\omega$.
3. The symplectic 2-form $\omega$ gives rise to a non-degenerate [Poisson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket) $\{\cdot,\cdot\}: C^{\infty}(M) \times C^{\infty}(M) \to C^{\infty}(M) $.
4. [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_%28Hamiltonian%29) can be viewed as the fact that *[Hamiltonian vector fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_vector_field) are divergencefree.*